# Verifying data consistency between data centers in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, distributed-system, data-consistency, nosql

I maintaining a cassandra cluster with 2 data centers. Now I am going to add new data center in that existing cluster. After rebuilding data, how can i verify the consistency of data in new data center?

Comment: What do  you mean by that? As in if the data is replicated correctly?

Comment: How can i ensure that data in old DC replicated completely in new DC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read with LOCAL_QUORUM from each DC and compare be most straight forward.

A repair builds a hash of partitions from the sstables in a compaction task and compares ranges of them which is more efficient than reading data individually. You could just pull that part out of code to build a tool to do same thing... or if you can just run a (full not incremental) repair. It logs about differences it finds.

Comment: Both suggestions are interesting, I guess the first one depends on the size of the data set, the second one sounds like a fun project

Comment: Running full repair will be IO intensive task. Any other suggestions? I have heard we could run spark job to do this. any idea on that?

Comment: a spark job would read all the data as well. Difference is after reading all the data the repair job will only send a merkle tree (hashes) of data to be compared while spark will stream all the data over to be compared. But if you want to know specifics a spark job or a script to read at local_quorum will give you more details.